# How to access parent's memory-mapped region in the child process?

Tags: linux, clone, mmap

I want to share a memory mapped region between 2 processes and use ptrace to "poke" data into it. According to [clone man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone), `CLONE_VM` flag is what I'm looking for, however, I can't seem to be able to access the mapping in the child process.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func A() {
    f, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "test")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f.Write([]byte("4321"))

    b, err := syscall.Mmap(int(f.Fd()), 0, 10, syscall.PROT_WRITE, syscall.MAP_SHARED)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("mmap", err)
    }

    maps, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/proc/self/maps")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("A maps:")
    fmt.Println(string(maps))

    cmd := exec.Command("/proc/self/exe", "B")
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Ptrace:     true,
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_VM | syscall.CLONE_PTRACE,
    }
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = syscall.Wait4(cmd.Process.Pid, nil, 0, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Wait4", err)
    }

    ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&b[0])
    log.Printf("PokeText into %p\n", ptr)

    // Poke text into the mmaped-region via ptrace
    _, err = syscall.PtracePokeText(cmd.Process.Pid, uintptr(ptr), []byte("1234"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("PokeText", err)
    }
}

func B() {
    _, _, errno := syscall.RawSyscall(syscall.SYS_PTRACE, uintptr(syscall.PTRACE_TRACEME), 0, 0)
    if errno != 0 {
        log.Fatal("TRACEME", errno)
    }
    log.Println("B exiting")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if flag.Arg(0) != "B" {
        A()
    } else {
        B()
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
A maps:
00400000-004ab000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 29942418                           /tmp/go-build924065198/b001/exe/a
004ab000-0055d000 r--p 000ab000 00:16 29942418                           /tmp/go-build924065198/b001/exe/a
0055d000-00573000 rw-p 0015d000 00:16 29942418                           /tmp/go-build924065198/b001/exe/a
00573000-00592000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
c000000000-c000001000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
c41fff8000-c420100000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe59696a000-7fe59696b000 -w-s 00000000 00:16 29942419                   /tmp/test112646167
7fe59696b000-7fe596a0b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd43a91000-7ffd43ab4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd43acc000-7ffd43ace000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd43ace000-7ffd43ad0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

2018/04/02 14:04:28 PokeText into 0x7fe59696a000
2018/04/02 14:04:28 PokeText input/output error
exit status 1
2018/04/02 14:04:28 B exiting
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want to share a buffer with a child process where two processes are collaborative? First of all, don't use `CLONE_VM`, it's mostly intended for threads. Second of all you're massively over-complicating a simple task of sharing a buffer between a parent and a child process.

Instead I would suggest [using memfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) and passing it to a child process. From there on the memory is shared, there is no need for ugly and slow ptrace calls. Keep in mind that you need locking to prevent the buffer from being concurrently modified by child and parent. This would require a low level primitive like [a futex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) to implement locking.

This is all highly Linux specific and since you're using `clone` I'm assuming portability is of no concern in my answer. I'll also assume you're using a reasonably recent kernel (`memfd` was mainlined in `3.17`).

**Sidenote**: since Linux `3.2` you get those two new wonderful syscalls: [process_vm_readv and process_vm_writev](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_writev.2.html) that should save you the trouble of having to use ptrace's poke (which as you may guess incurs a massive penalty of constantly switching into the kernel).

**Sidenote 2**: since you're not using C I would suggest using your language's mechanism for executing a child process, there is no reason to use `clone` there. All you need to do is a way to pass a file descriptor to a child process (a UNIX domain socket or a non `CLOEXEC` file descriptor come to mind).

**Edit**: It seems that you're trying to share a mmap'd file between a parent and a child and are doing in a way that bypasses all the kernel machinery that's there to allow for this to "just work". Pass the fd to the child, the kernel will take care of the rest. Or reopen the file in the child. Either works, it's a common technique used by databases.

---

**Edit 2**: If I understand correctly from the comments this is an attempt to execute the [Dirty COW](https://dirtycow.ninja/) exploit that relies on a *private* mapping and a *race condition* within the kernel's VM subsystem.

Doing it from a garbage collected language (Go) that depends on a large runtime and may do a lot of things like memory allocations as side effects of pretty much anything is a bad way of going about triggering a race condition. Using a shared mapping defeats the point of the exploit in this case. I'm still confused as to what you're trying to accomplish but if it's to replicate the exploit in Go I would suggest not doing that, it just isn't the right tool for the job.

Also you're trying to exploit access elevation to a file you already seem to have write access to? That seems to make even less sense. Bottom line is, I think before attempting to replicate an exploit it's important to consider the semantics of the exploit, and where a high level language may not be quite suitable.

Comment: Performance is not an issue here. I need to write to a `mmap`-ed file from another process using `ptrace`.

Comment: Try `MAP_SHARED` and passing the fd to the child? This concept dates way back before dynamic linking was even a thing. That's sort of the point of having this type of functionality, you have an OS, your program doesn't exist in a vacuum.

Comment: `MAP_SHARED` is already used.
Essentially, I'm trying to do [this](https://github.com/dirtycow/dirtycow.github.io/blob/master/pokemon.c), but in Go.

Comment: You're trying to exploit a bug that depends on triggering a race condition in the kernel in a garbage collected language that is heavily dependent on its runtime and may spontaneously allocate memory (and has no generics)? Also the code in question uses a private mapping and writes to it, it abuses mmap's copy-on-write semantics (hence the `COW` part) to be able to execute this. Also pthread_create's clone has different semantics to the above, see the `glibc` implementation.

Comment: Obviously, I changed the mappings to show the actual problem.